# How to solve the error : "Sorry, installation of this driver failed. Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log"

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04  and on updating driver from GUI additional driver, it prompts me for the missing of broadcom driver . on accepting the download option. the message get prompted

```
Sorry, installation of this driver failed.

Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log
```

i am new with ubuntu can any one suggest how can i over come this issue and get wifi network enabled on my `compaq presario kernel 3.8`

Comment: List down the content of the log file.. what is the output of `sudo vi /var/log/jockey.log`

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package by issuing the following command on a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Install firmware-b43-installer and the b43-fwcutter packages if they are not installed

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```

Type into terminal:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep 'bcm'
```

Copy this and see if the term 'blacklist bcm43xx' is there

if it is, type `cd /etc/modprobe.d/` and then `sudo gedit blacklist.conf`

put  # in front of the line: blacklist bcm43xx

Now save the file then reboot.

For more info check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx)

Comment: :on running installing command i get this ::
 Reading package lists...
 Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer

Comment: Before you proceed, let's identify your wireless device. Please edit your question to add: lspci -nn | grep 0280